# Rails: get a migration error for indexing jsonb with gist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, indexing, rails-migrations, jsonb

With my rails app I try to create an `Order` model and in my migration I have this line of code:

```
add_index :orders, :data, unique: false, using: :gist
```

But when I try to migrate I have the following error:

```
PG::UndefinedObject:ERROR: data type jsonb has no default operator class for access method "gist"
```

I also tried a migration with gin and it work nicely, I rolled back and then tried again with gist and I have the samme error, I already have btree_gist extension enabled in both databases (test and develoment) and checked in pgadmin and db/schema.rb file.

I don't know if I missed something or if there are issue with rails and windows and any help is welcome.